# Проверка версии платформы .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net

Необходимо чтобы при запуске программы (обязательно C#) происходила проверки наличия установленного .NET Framework 3.5 и выше.

Пока есть два варианта решения проблемы:
1. Открывать программу .NET Framework 2.0 и если проходит проверка, то запускать на версии выше. 
2. Писать в другой среде, которая может проверить наличие .NET Framework как такового и после чего уже запускать программу.

Хотелось бы услышать ваши мнения.

По первому пункту я не могу найти как поменять запускаемую платформу и как потом перейти на другую программу.
По второму - на чём писать и, опять таки, как запустить программу написанную в C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не-не, так не катит.

Программа должна не просто запускаться, а инсталлироваться на клиентской машине. Инсталляция включает установку всех необходимых redistributables, включая и нужную версию .NET. Это значит, что если ваш target — платформа младше Windows 7 (на которой .NET 3.5 ставится [автоматически](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#Overview)), вам нужно таскать с собой либо полный redistributable, либо web-инсталлятор.

В любом случае, проверка и инсталляция необходимых библиотек — это проблема не программы, а её инсталлятора.

Answer (score 3):

Помимо ответа *@VladD*, с которым я полностью согласен, в голову приходит ещё пару вариантов:

1. Вместе с программой поставляйте .config-файл с указанием необходимой платформы (подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w4atty68(v=vs.110).aspx)), пример содержания конфигурационного файла:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <startup> 
       <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
     </startup>
   </configuration>
   ```

   В теории, при отсутствии нужной версии платформы, должно будет появиться окно с запросом на установку нужной версии framework'а.
2. Сделать небольшое вспомогательное приложение - bootstrapper (собранное под второй framework, если оно на .net, или простое нативное приложение на любом языке), которое при запуске проверит версию Framework'а (лучше всего по реестру), и если всё плохо, то сообщит об этом, а если всё хорошо - запустит основное приложение.